# Using git attributes from command line

Tags: regex, git, attributes

I have this configuration on my repo:

```
echo '*.java diff=java' >> .gitattributes
```

and when I do `git diff ...` I get the expected results.

However, I'm doing a script to analyse other git repositories, so I usually do:

```
git --git-dir='/path/to/repo/.git' diff ...
```

What I would like to do is to run the script like that, and have the same results as if the attribute was present. I don't want to set global attributes or add a .gitattributes to the git project I want to analyse. I wouldn't mind something like

```
git --git-dir='/path/to/repo/.git' diff --word-diff-regex=<java-rexeg>
```

But I don't know how to get the java regex git uses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `git help config`:

> `core.attributesfile`
>
> In addition to `.gitattributes` (per-directory) and .git/info/attributes, git looks into this file for attributes (see `gitattributes(5)`). Path expansions are made the same way as for `core.excludesfile`. Its default value is $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/attributes. If `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` is either not set or empty, `$HOME/.config/git/attributes` is used instead.

In other words, you can create your own attributes file at `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/attributes`, and pass `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` to your git invocation like this:

```
XDG_CONFIG_HOME=config_dir git --git-dir='/path/to/repo/.git' diff ...
```

Because you control exactly what is `XDG_CONFIG_HOME`, it would not be truly global - you can do it totally on a fly.

Or, it may be simpler to create global git attributes file in `$HOME/.config/git/attributes` instead.

Comment: Using `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` worked. This is the solution I was looking for, because I don't need to do anything outside the script (if I go to another machine, `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` will still be on the script tree structure and there's no need to change anything). Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use shell's process substitution to avoid using any files at all:

```
git -c core.attributesFile=<(echo '*.java diff=java) --git-dir='/path/to/repo/.git' diff --word-diff-regex=<java-rexeg>
```