# How to set file attributes in .gitattributes file via command line

Tags: gitlab, gitattributes

I want to edit some of the file attributes inside my .gitattributes file. How can I do that via command line without checking out the file and committing the file again after making the changes?

e.g. we can see the file attributes via the `git check-attr -a *.txt` command (to display all attributes of the .txt files). I need a similar way to set file attributes.

Comment: Similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18950604/using-git-attributes-from-command-line

Answer (score 0):

The attributes definition does not necessarily come from a file that resides inside the project database, it really depends on the scope that you want for these attributes. From the git help:

> If you wish to affect only a single repository (i.e., to assign attributes to files that are particular to one user’s workflow for that repository), then attributes should be placed in the $GIT_DIR/info/attributes file. Attributes which should be version-controlled and distributed to other repositories (i.e., attributes of interest to all users) should go into .gitattributes files. Attributes that should affect all repositories for a single user should be placed in a file specified by the core.attributesFile configuration option (see git-config[1]). Its default value is $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/attributes. If $XDG_CONFIG_HOME is either not set or empty, $HOME/.config/git/attributes is used instead. Attributes for all users on a system should be placed in the $(prefix)/etc/gitattributes file.

So, if you really need to set the file attributes for all the users of your project, you have no solution but to commit your `.gitattributes` file.

If you want to set the attributes to your local version of the project:

1. change file attributes from the git tool: this can only be done using `git config`, but only for a subset of the attributes (eol) and for all files
2. you can change the file located in `$GIT_DIR/info/attributes`